# Calculate table's record count for one of Version Date under in same dataset

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

There are at least two tables look likes below which under the same dataset.
And only one field `VERSION_DATE` are match with them.

Here I want to calculate all the record count when `Version_DATE` is equal to one specific date.
For example `2021-01-01`.

**TABLE A**

| VERSION_DATE | STUDENT_SCORE |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | 88 |
| 2021-01-01 | 98 |
| 2021-01-02 | 38 |
| 2021-01-02 | 48 |
| 2021-01-02 | 100 |

**TABLE B**

| VERSION_DATE | CITY_SCORE | NAME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | 45 | A |
| 2021-01-01 | 72 | B |
| 2021-01-01 | 53 | C |
| 2021-01-01 | 83 | D |
| 2021-01-02 | 16 | A |

**Expected Result:**

| VERSION_DATE | COUNT |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | 6 |

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just use [UNION ALL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#set_operators)

```
select version_date, count(*)
from (
  select version_date from table_a where version_date = '2021-01-01'
  union all
  select version_date from table_b where version_date = '2021-01-01'
)
```

Comment: That's an easy and good way to solve!!

But my actual pain points is that I don't know how many tables in a dataset 
There will not efficient if we still union all tables one by one. 
Particularly, there are 50 or even more. 

Is there another way to generate the same result by not using Union all ?

Comment: @SimonGan . . . You should be using partitioned tables so you don't have this problem.

Comment: Yes, you are right.
But it show Unrecognized name: _PARTITIONDATE when I use it. 
I also check the table type in 'details' -- Partitioned by Day 
Partitioned on field VERSION_DATE

Answer (score 0):

Try below, but it really depends on what other tables in your dataset that match the `table*` pattern - if all of them have `VERSION_DATE` field  - you should be OK. But if not it depends on the most recent created or updated table with same name pattern - it must have such field - otherwise below query will fail

```
select VERSION_DATE, count(1) as `COUNT`
from `yourdataset.table*`   
where _table_suffix in ('a', 'b')
group by VERSION_DATE
```